# Draw 2D Curve in XNA

Tags: c#, xna

Is there any way to generate a Curve class and then draw that curve in 2D on the screen in XNA?

I want to basically randomly generate some terrain using the Curve and then draw it.  Hoping that I can then use that curve to detect collision with the ground.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like what you want is the 2D equivalent of a height-map. I'd avoid making a true "curve" and simply approximate one with line segments.

So basically you'll have an array or list of numbers that represent the height of your terrain at a series evenly spaced (horizontally) points. When you need a height between two points, you simply linearly interpolate between the two.

**To generate it** - you could set a few points randomly, and then do some form of smooth interpolation to set the rest. (It really depends on what kind of curve you want.)

**To render it** you could then just use a triangle strip. Each point in your height-map will have two vertices associated with it - one at the bottom of the screen, the other at the height of that point in the height-map.

**To do collision detection** - the easiest way is to have your objects be a single point (it sounds like you're making a artillery game like Scorched Earth) - simply take the X position of your object, get the Y position of your terrain at that X position, if the Y position of your object is below the terrain, set it so that it is on the terrain's surface.

That's the rough guide, anyway :)